# Translate text in config folder cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, php-7.2, cakephp-3.6

I'm trying to internationalize a CakePHP 3 application using **cake i18n extract**. All the texts coming from **src** folder are translated fine, but I have some text that I put inside **config/bootstrap.php** but those don't get translated even though I placed them inside the double underscore function **__('My text')** and I also generated the translation files in **src/Locale** folder (the same way I did for the other texts that work.

Any idea why my texts in **config/bootstrap.php** won't get translated?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

They do not show up because by default the extract task only looks in the `src` folder. When running the task it will ask you from what paths to extract, and it should only list the `src` folder by default.

You can either add your custom paths interactively in the shell when it asks you for the folders that should be looked up, or you can use the `paths` option to define them in beforehand, like:

```
bin/cake i18n extract --paths /var/www/app/config,/var/www/app/src
```

When doing so may also want to use the `output` option to specify the output path, as the task will use the first path as the root for output, ie with the above paths it would put the files in `config/Locale` instead of `src/Locale`. Alternatively you can switch the paths, but then the messages from the `config` folder files would appear at the bottom of the `.pot` file.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Console Tools, Shells & Tasks > I18N Shell > Generating POT Files > Extracting from multiple folders at once](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html#extracting-from-multiple-folders-at-once)**

Comment: I did that, but the translated versions of the texts are not showing up on the page. Even after I deleted all cache files.

Comment: @user765368 So, have I misread your question, you have extracted the messages, they are present and translated in your (`.po`) translation file, but show up untranslated? If so, please update your question and show where exactly in the `bootstrap.php` file you are using the translation funtions, and where exactly you are setting/switching the current locale.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you set the application locale with I18n::setLocale(). Your application using App.defaultLocale setting to determinate wich language sould be shown.
If you change your language in your controller, your configuration files already loaded so this will not effect on these files just on those files what will be loaded after your setLocale.

Try to change your language **before** translatable files loaded, or load translate configuration files in controller after changeing the appLocale.